A clarification needed on importing JavaScript files on PnPjs instead of their counterparts typescript files
I am new to typescript and PnPjs and I found on some files on packages/sp folder like index.ts there is an import for JavaScript files like (../fi.js) instead of importing directly from ../fi.ts file , Why that ?
in the meantime typescript files inside the "samples" folder (like samples/spfx-react-components/src/webparts/pnPjs/components/ PnPjsWebPart.ts) are referencing other typescript files instead of referencing  their compiled JavaScript files
